# How return specific embedded document fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query

regards, suppose we have the following documents in my collection called `inventory` and I'm trying to show only the incoming movements inventory:

```
[
    {
      "_id": "638150ee268d890e9983881f",
      "movements": {
        "entries": [
          {
            "code": 4,
            "created_at": "2022-11-25T23:31:38.523Z",
            "created_by": "userId",
            "type": "Ingreso",
            "observation": "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted",
            "old_quantity": 0,
            "new_quantity": 10,
            "total_quantity": 10
          },...
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "_id": "63810f179db70fea1263dea5",
      "movements": {
        "entries": [
          {
            "code": 1,
            "created_at": "2022-11-25T18:52:54.528Z",
            "created_by": "userId",
            "type": "Ingreso",
            "observation": "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted",
            "old_quantity": 0,
            "new_quantity": 100,
            "total_quantity": 100
          },...
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
```

This is the response request from my api, until here its ok, but I would like to show something like this:

```
[
    {
      "code": 4,
      "created_at": "2022-11-25T23:31:38.523Z",
      "created_by": "userId",
      "type": "Ingreso",
      "observation": "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted",
      "old_quantity": 0,
      "new_quantity": 10,
      "total_quantity": 10
    },
    {
      "code": 5,
      "created_at": "2022-11-25T23:31:38.523Z",
      "created_by": "userId",
      "type": "Ingreso",
      "observation": "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted",
      "old_quantity": 10,
      "new_quantity": 20,
      "total_quantity": 30
    }, 
    {
      "code": 1,
      "created_at": "2022-11-25T18:52:54.528Z",
      "created_by": "userId",
      "type": "Ingreso",
      "observation": "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted",
      "old_quantity": 0,
      "new_quantity": 100,
      "total_quantity": 100
    },
    {
      "code": 2,
      "created_at": "2022-11-25T18:52:54.528Z",
      "created_by": "userId",
      "type": "Ingreso",
      "observation": "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted",
      "old_quantity": 100,
      "new_quantity": 100,
      "total_quantity": 200
    },...
  ]
```

I don't know if it's possible to do it this way. If it is not possible at least I would expect to suppress the embedded elements of the document; leaving in a first level `entries` array. Something like this:

```
[
    {
      "_id": "638150ee268d890e9983881f",
      "entries": [
        {
          "code": 4,
          "created_at": "2022-11-25T23:31:38.523Z",
          "created_by": "userId",
          "type": "Ingreso",
          "observation": "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted",
          "old_quantity": 0,
          "new_quantity": 10,
          "total_quantity": 10
        }...
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "63810f179db70fea1263dea5",
      "entries": [
        {
          "code": 1,
          "created_at": "2022-11-25T18:52:54.528Z",
          "created_by": "userId",
          "type": "Ingreso",
          "observation": "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted",
          "old_quantity": 0,
          "new_quantity": 100,
          "total_quantity": 100
        }...
      ]
    }
  ];
```

As each document contains other information, for the purposes of this example I am only focusing on displaying the incoming inventory movement data so I have implemented the following and it works, but not as I would expect (mentioned above):

```
return this.connect().then((db) => {
      return db
        .collection(collection)
        .find({ is_deleted: false })
        .project({ movements: { entries: 1 } })
        .sort({ _id: -1 })
        .toArray();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the projection, set `entries` field with the value of `movements.entries`.

```js
return this.connect().then((db) => {
      return db
        .collection(collection)
        .find({ is_deleted: false })
        .project({
          entries: "$movements.entries"
        })
        .sort({ _id: -1 })
        .toArray();
    });
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/v-VNaFrJ_cG)

Comment: Sorry, the property "data" is just the response from API, I've changed the result from MongoDB

Comment: this returns only the id's of every array `[
    {
      "_id": "63810f179db70fea1263dea5"
    },
    {
      "_id": "638150ee268d890e9983881f"
    }
  ]`

Comment: Sorry typo error, should be `movements.entries`.

Comment: yesssssssssssssssss that was correct! I was reading and found the 's' was missing. Thanks!